# Space craft in a forest on a different planet, small glowing crystal

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is an 70s or 80s movie, I last saw it as a small child so bear with me.

It involves a space craft in the middle of a forest on a different planet. Maybe the ship crashed? A blond woman actor in the ship with possibly a child? No helmet or oxygen needed on the planet.

The setting has almost a Star Wars feel to it. I vaguely remember something about a small glowing crystal and even fairy like creatures.

Comment: Could be Star Crystal (1986) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVHI42HN8Hs

Comment: Anyone else thinking this could be Caravan of Courage? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2OaBk89KyU

Comment: actually probably no one is thinking of Caravan of Courage. Terrible terrible film!

Comment: @skyjack - I went to see that at the cinema. I quite liked it.

Comment: That’s it! Caravan of courage! That you all so much!

Comment: @Valorum That played in cinemas?  I thought it was a direct-to-TV release...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Both the Ewoks films played near where I live

Comment: @Jluv1185 glad to be of service, you can mark this answer as correct if you have a moment

Comment: I saw this in the cinema too, It was made for TV in the US but did get a cinema release in the UK. I also recall seeing some episodes of Battlestar Galactica in the cinema that had been stitched together to make something film length.

Answer (score 9):

After having made a couple of cheeky comments I actually think that this could be [*Caravan of Courage: An Ewok Adventure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravan_of_Courage:_An_Ewok_Adventure).

Made mid-1980s so fits your timescale. Star Wars feel as it's a *Star Wars* spin off. Forest setting. Crashed Spaceship. Fairy like creatures called "Wisties" (would not have recalled that, thank you google). Blond child, not sure about a blond adult woman but there is a blond teenage boy... Not sure about a glowing crystal so there is room for error here.

Watch the trailer here...

For an image of a Wistie see this page on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Izrina).

Comment: There definitely is a glowing crystal in *The Ewok Adventure*.  (I think they used to to hypnotize the giant spider.)